# How to make a Button style global throughout the project while using tailwind with angular

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I am a beginner and I have been working on angular and decided to use tailwind for the styling, since every tailwind class is inline a style class for a button becomes huge and in order to use that button I have to use that class everywhere. which makes the code look overwhelming and maintenance becomes a pain.

My question is how to make a button style global using tailwind also I have buttons with multiple styles like `button-no-bg` , `button-bg-red`

I tried defining them in the `styles.css` of angular using `@apply` directive

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities; 
.button-no-bg{
  @apply bg-white text-blue-500 border p-1 px-8  text-xs font-bold border-blue-500;
}
.button-red-bg{
  @apply ......;
}
```

To avoid code duplication, I want to know how to make a button class global with multiple button names and their associated classes. If not the whole answer please share the reference.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, because that how you define global custom class apply other classes in Tailwind, can you share your package.json and tailwind.config.js

Comment: [package.json](https://gist.github.com/sBhavish/4cbaad7d730674e692684d0cc645a9fd) and [tailwind.config.js](https://gist.github.com/sBhavish/4382317e77c76d09b7106ad48a10475e) these are the requested file @Tony

Comment: I just tried it locally, and couldn't reproduce the problem. I suggest you to delete node_module folder and npm i again, because there is apparently some cache or file issue that is not reproducible with a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very very newbie in tailwinds with angular and not pretty sure this way is the "better" way, but waiting another better response...

go on the instructions in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular), but **Not include** the @tailwinds in styles.css else in a new file `styles-tailwinds.css`

execute at time

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/styles-tailwinds.css -o ./src/output.css --watch
//and
ng serve
```

The first make that any change in styles-tailwinds.css create a new file in src/output.css

Edit your angular.json to add this .css, so the array styles becomes like

```
  "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/output.css"
        ],
```